# Webview images won't load on real device

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am retrieving an HTML document in a `WebView` that contains URLs to images. When I run the app on the emulator, everything is working fine. But when it comes to run on a real device, I can see nothing.

This is what I am using:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.loadUrl(url);

private class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Again, everything is working fine on an emulator but not on a real device.

Even if I generate the apk it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did your device access to that `URL`? check that in your device browser.

Comment: @javadroid yes, i said that it works fine on the emulator

Comment: may be your emulator has different connection. just check the url in your device browser. if is open as well, try the way that @mehrdad says below.

Comment: @javadroid i tried it many times and even with the condition for kitkat and up but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i forgot to mention. i also tried that but it didnt work